# GWT Label alignments and CSS

Tags: html, css, gwt

I am having some trouble with GWT Labels and html/css.

I have a horizontalPanel, and I am trying to align the 2 labels so that each 1 is on an end of the Horizontal Panel

```
1) [Label 1      --~500px--      Label 2]
```

However, it seems that the 500 px is divided up into 250px each for a label, and theres a white space. (First I tried to make it like like this)

```
2) [Label 1 Label 2 --~500 whitespace px-- ]
```

but what happens is this

```
3) [Label 1 -~250 whitespace px- Label 2 -~250px whitespace-- ]
```

I would like It to be like 2) so then i can set the HorizontalAllignment on the Horizontal Panel to ALIGN_JUSTIFY which would put on one each end. I have no idea how to do it. I tried using display: inline but that doesnt seem to work as I hoped (it makes the border just go around the text but the whitespace is there)

Here is the code I am messing around with .border is just (border: 1px solid Red) so i can visualize how the border and size is calculated

```
HorizontalPanel p = new HorizontalPanel();

p.setWidth("500px");


//p.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
//p.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_JUSTIFY);
Label l1 = new Label("Label 1");
Label l2 = new Label("Label 2");

l1.addStyleName("border");
l2.addStyleName("border");

p.add(l1);
p.add(l2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just threw this together from memory, give it a try and let me know if it works like you expect.

```
HorizontalPanel p = new HorizontalPanel();

p.setWidth("500px");
p.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_JUSTIFY);

Label l1 = new Label("Label 1");
Label l2 = new Label("Label 2");

l1.addStyleName("border");
l2.addStyleName("border");

p.add(l1);
p.setCellHorizontalAlignment(l1, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
p.add(l2);
p.setCellHorizontalAlignment(l2, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

If that doesn't work, have you tried setting `text-align:right;` in your css for the second label?

Comment: yes, that does work exactly like i'd expect. there is still one thing however. each label is taking up roughly 250px. Ideally i'd want it so that the label takes up as much space as it needs and the rest is free space (right the label is 250px long but should take up ~50px). if I apply display:inline to each label, it does fix the problem but I am new to 'display: inline' and I am not sure about other implications it may have. even if there is no solution for that, your method should work! thank you.